# moduli of effective divisors of a projective manifold projective

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Are the moduli of effective divisors of a complex projective 2-manifold projective. If so a reference?

Comment: may be you should ask in MO. This question does not get anough attention in between 100 elementary posts..

Comment: This is a fine question to ask here. If you don't get answers for a couple days, reposting on MO is a good move.

Comment: Much more general statements are true, stated correctly. Clearly, there are numerical constraints (for example, the intersection number of a divisor with a fixed hyperplane section is a discrete invariant) so, there will be disjoint collection of such moduli. But, once we fix these numbers, you do get projective varieties and I suggest you look up Hilbert Schemes.